# Formatting textbox string for currency

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, format, currency

I have a textbox in WPF and I would like to dynamically show the currency symbol, i.e. when the user edits the textbox and the textbox loses the focus, the currency symbol is automatically inserted at the end (beginning). I prefer it in XAML rather than hard-coding.
I would like to mention that my textbox is **not binded** to anything.

Comment: If you got some idea on IValueConverter, you can write the symbol to be shown either hard-coded or perhaps reading the symbol from some config/resource file and bind the converter to the currency textbox. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the easiest approach

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='$#,##0.0000;$(#,##0.0000)'}" />
```

value is your double or decimal money 
but you said it's "not binded to anything" i can't see how is that possible but you can do it by code if you want like so

```
value.ToString("$#,##0.0000;$(#,##0.0000)");
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [Masked TextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox) that is part of the [Extended WPF ToolKit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/). Or [Google](https://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&=&q=masked%20textbox%20wpf&oq=masked%20te&aq=5&aqi=g4g-s1g1g-s1g3&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=1017846l1020563l0l1027625l9l9l0l2l2l0l93l390l5l5l0) WPF Masked TextBox for other options.